# Get homescreen icons back to normal size

Tags: home-screen, google-pixel-4a

My dad's phone (google pixel 4a, latest android version) seems to have changed the size of the icons on the home screen while in his pocket. Is it somehow possible to get this back to normal?

We have so far tried the following things:

- check display & font size in the accessibility menu is set to default
- there is no option to customize the icon size by holding an empty spot in the screen (only the ability to switch the launcher)
- we weren't able to find an option to change the grid layout on the home screen

There is no custom theme/home screen/launcher installed

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Which launcher app are you using? If you don't know what I mean, than tell us the Android device and Android version you are using.

Comment: The device is a google pixel 4a using the latest version of android

Comment: Long press on the empty space on home screen  and choose Grid. Change it to 5x5. For help, see https://www.xda-developers.com/download-pixel-launcher-google-pixel-5-adds-grid-size-options/

Comment: Check if *magnification* is enabled under accessibility settings

Comment: @Firelord there is no option there, the website you specified was for pixel 5 and 4a 5G, this is a Pixel 4 however.

Comment: On my Pixel 3a, assuming the launcher app is still the stock Pixel Launcher, I just replicated the issue by long-pressing the empty space on the home screen, choosing "Styles & wallpapers" (alternatively, accessible from Settings-Display), selecting "Grid", choosing "2x2", then pressing the checkmark on the bottom right. But I'd be surprised if it was done accidentally...

Comment: @AndrewT. I am using the Pixel 3a as well, could you maybe tell me what version of the pixel launcher you are using (I am using version 11)

Comment: Same version 11, on Android 11. If that's the case, what did you mean by "the ability to switch the launcher"? Is there any other launcher? What launcher is shown on Settings - Apps & notifications - Advanced - Default apps - Home app?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you for replecating the issue. This may sound really stupid. Even so I am using the same Smartphone and version I am unable to find it. [Here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/PDTKewRNH1XZX3FU9) is a recoding of me going through the menus.

Comment: @AndrewT. I can only report what my dad is saying about his phone, since I am in a different country. I will ask him to take a screenshot.

Comment: I also am using the Pixel 4a, and for me, there is a "Raster" tab next to the style and wallpaper tab. I'm on the latest security patch level, your Dad may try to update to the latest version and see if this issue persists?

Comment: @AndrewT.  Thank you very much, appearantly he must have overlooked it, only when I asked him to take a screenshot he realized it. It wouldn't have been possible without your help to solve it, since I am unable to replicate it on my phone.

Comment: @BenjyTec Thank you very much, he must have overlooked it.